# Keep user in the same div after submit button clicked if the textbox empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a problem that I'm trying to figure out from past 2 days but still no solution found.
I have a html page with 4 div.
each div has has 3 input fields and a button. 
If the text box is empty then the user should be in the same div even after submit button clicked but in my case they are getting redirected to another div.
how do i solve this issue?
also show warning and not allow user to proceed next if the textbox is empty.

code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">          
                  <label> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane px-2"> </i> Send To Address</label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="a1" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
                  </div>
                  </div>      
                 <div class="col-sm-12">          
                  <label style="width: 100% !important"> <i class="fa fa-money px-2"> </i> Amount <span class="pull-right"> Max Amount: --- </span></label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="x1"class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Amount">
                  </div>
                  </div> 
                  <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                  <span class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn1" id="b1"> <small> Continue </small> </span>      
                  </div>          
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane t2" id="account">
                      <h5 class="info-text"> </h5>
                      <div class="row justify-content-center">

                  <div class="col-sm-12">          
                  <label> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane px-2"> </i> Send To Address</label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Address" disabled>
                  </div>
                  </div>      
                 <div class="col-sm-12">          
                 <label style="width: 100% !important"> <i class="fa fa-money px-2"> </i> Amount <span class="pull-right"> Max Amount: --- </span></label>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="Amount Entered" disabled>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#b1').click(function(){
            if ($('input#a1#x1').val() == ""){
                alert('Please complete the field');
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tried many solutions but all just show the warning but still redirect to another div
please help!!

Comment: why downvote? just why?

Comment: post your jquery code also, if first one is open remaining all div should hide or not?

Comment: they will be visible when the user clicks on submit to proceed next

Comment: I can keep the button disabled until all textbox are filled but i don't need that.

Comment: @rokoja, how are you submitting your form? where are you submitting it to? I don't see any form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, I see that It can pass the validation even I just put some white-space so you should use the trim on your code.

for example

```
$.trim($('#a1').val())
```

Why I call put the whole statement in $.trim because in Earlier time, if I called .trim() on value it's break in IE7.

The 2nd thing you need is focus in jQuery, for example if you want to focus on some input tag. Simply call

```
$("#a1").focus();
```

the naming convention you are using doesn't look well. You should name the div in a convention you can understand the code easily.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is "focus". You are trying to keep keyboard focus on a particular input (textbox).

You simply use jQuery's [`focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) function to set keyboard focus on a particular input.

However, you will want to use this sparingly. Sometimes users move from textbox to textbox in a different order then you had imagined. Perhaps they're reading information off a piece of paper and filling it in according to that order. Jumping the keyboard focus around unexpectedly can make your website harder to use, so be careful when setting the focus.

Comment: I have tried but still get the same issue as mentioned in the question

Comment: I can keep the button disabled until all textbox are filled but i don't need that.

Comment: @rojoka Please show use what you've tried. As-is, I can't tell where the problem is. All you've posted is an `alert`. Show us the "many solutions".